# jest enzyme TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am writing test and below is my test case.

```
import { mount, jest } from 'enzyme';

it('should submit job post form on save button click', () => {
        const onPostJobSubmit = jest.fn(); // Here is the error.
        const instance = wrapper.instance();
        wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
        expect(onPostJobSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

When I run test I get below error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

      61 |
      62 |  it('should submit job post form on save button click', () => {
    > 63 |      const onPostJobSubmit = jest.fn();
```

What is wrong with that and how can I fix this?

Comment: `enzyme` doesn't have `jest`. Use `jest` global object instead

Comment: @slideshowp2 so how can I import jest to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [doc](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object):

> The `jest` object is automatically in scope within every test file. The methods in the jest object help create mocks and let you control Jest's overall behavior. It can also be imported explicitly by via `import {jest} from '@jest/globals'`.

Comment: OK. I got that part but the problem now is that when I run test I get this `Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

      64 |   const instance = wrapper.instance();
      65 |   wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
    > 66 |   expect(onPostJobSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();` It seems like it is not getting called any idea why?

Comment: @Om3ga It's hard to tell without the component code under test. You'd better ask a new question with the component code